# How do I tell the SentryWebpackPlugin the name of my source map?

Tags: typescript, webpack, sentry

1) The code for my webpage is written in TypeScript and I use WebPack to bundle it into a "main.min.js" file for the end-user. (Pretty standard stuff.)

2) I want to utilize the [Sentry.io](https://sentry.io/welcome/) service to automatically report errors to the cloud, so I've installed the `@sentry/browser` package and initialized it in my TypeScript codebase. So far so good - my webpage successfully reports errors to Sentry.

3) However, the reported errors do not contain the real line numbers, e.g. the source maps. In order to fix this, [the Sentry documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/sourcemaps/) says that you need to use the `SentryWebpackPlugin`. So, I've installed that, and changed my WebPack config to be the following:

```
import SentryWebpackPlugin from '@sentry/webpack-plugin';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as webpack from 'webpack';

// Constants
const epoch = new Date().getTime();

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
    // The entry file to bundle
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'main.ts'),

    // Where to put the bundled file
    output: {
        path: __dirname, // By default, Webpack will output the file to a "dist" subdirectory
        filename: 'main.min.js',
        // Chrome caches source maps and will not update them even after a hard-refresh
        // Work around this by putting the epoch timestamp in the source map filename
        sourceMapFilename: `main.min.js.${epoch}.map`,
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.json'],
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a ".ts" extension (TypeScript files) will be handled by "ts-loader"
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                loader: 'ts-loader',
            },
        ],
    },

    plugins: [
        new SentryWebpackPlugin({
            include: './main.min.js',
        }),
    ],

    // Enable source maps
    devtool: 'source-map',
};

export default config;
```

This is an extremely basic WebPack configuration with one exception - a custom source map filename. By default, most source maps take the filename of "main.min.js.map" for a "main.min.js" file. However, notice that in the above config, I change it to be "main.min.js.1586110008375.map" to get around the bug where Chrome caches source maps and will not update them even after a hard-refresh.

4) Now, when I tell WebPack to bundle my code, the new Sentry plugin complains that it cannot find the source map:

```
Source Map Upload Report
  Minified Scripts
    ~/main.min.js (sourcemap at backend.js.map)
      - warning: could not determine a source map reference (Could not auto-detect referenced sourcemap for ~/main.min.js.)
```

**How do I tell the SentryWebpackPlugin what the name of my custom source map is?**

The GitHub page is [here](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-webpack-plugin) and the docs are [here](https://docs.sentry.io/cli/releases/#sentry-cli-sourcemaps), but they do not seem to mention how to do this seemingly-trivial thing.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

check your `productionSourceMap: true`, when it's true,you can get sourcemap